# how to declare a dictionary inside two arrays

Tags: swift

How can I declare a multi array outside its function so i can use it outside its function? I know how to do a regular array and a regular dictionary, but not both.

```
IhelpersCoordinates = [
    [
        "Latitude":IhelpersLatitude,
        "Longitude": IhelpersLongitude,
        "userId": IhelpersUid
    ]
]
```

The code above is in the viewDidLoad. I'm trying to use it in the user did update function. I know with a regular array i have to set the array outside of the function (example- `var IhelpersCordinates = []`). I'm trying to figure out how i would do the same with the array above.

Comment: can you explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Just declare it outside the function... It is called instance variable or class property...

Comment: @MazelTov i know that i have to declare it outside but i dont know the correct way to write it because it is a dictionary inside an array inside an array  [ [ " ":" " ] ]

Comment: Your code in answer shows us an array with dictionary inside. Not dictionary inside an array inside an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your problem correctly you can declare a dictionary inside array use [[String:Double]].

```
class YourClass {
        var IhelpersCoordinates : [[String:Double]] = [
            [
                    "Latitude": 53.02,
                    "Longitude": 19.04,
                    "userId": 123
            ],
            [
                    "Latitude": 51.02,
                    "Longitude": 20.04,
                    "userId": 124
            ],

    ]

    func exampleFunc(){
        print(IhelpersCoordinates[0]["Latitude"]) // this will print 53.02
        print(IhelpersCoordinates.count) // this will print 2, because it's 2 elements array of dictionaries.
    }
}
```

**Edited base on comment**

If you want to declare an `dictionary inside an array inside an array` try this code :

```
class YourClass {

    var IhelpersCoordinates : Array<Array<[String:Double]>> = [
            [
                    [
                            "Latitude": 53.02,
                            "Longitude": 19.04,
                            "userId": 123
                    ],

            ],
            [
                    [
                            "Latitude": 53.02,
                            "Longitude": 19.04,
                            "userId": 123
                    ],

            ],
    ]

    func exampleFunc(){
        print(IhelpersCoordinates[0][0]["Latitude"])
        print(IhelpersCoordinates.count)
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

```
class YourClass {
    public var IhelpersCoordinates = Array<Array<[String:Double]>>()

    func calculate() {
        var element  = [
            [
                    "Latitude": 53.02,
                    "Longitude": 19.04,
                    "userId": 123
            ]
        ]
        var element1  = [
            [
                    "Latitude": 54.02,
                    "Longitude": 19.04,
                    "userId": 122
            ]
        ]

        self.IhelpersCoordinates.append(element)
        self.IhelpersCoordinates.append(element1)
    }

    func printValues() {
        print(self.IhelpersCoordinates.count)
    }
}
```

Hope it help you

Comment: the coordinates are calculated from another function so i cannot place place them inside of the function i wanted to do something like this outside the class       var IhelpersCoordinates : [[String:Double]] = [ : ]  <---  xcode recommend adding this but it does not work

Comment: You need to initialize your `IhelpersCoordinates ` using `Array<Array<[String:Double]>>()`